# dotnet KeyVault Certificate client - Certificate issued by a non-integrated CA

Tags: .net, certificate, azure-keyvault

Using the dotnet KeyVault Certificate Client is it possible to perform the following actions?:

**Create a certificate that's "Certificate issued by a non-integrated CA". Putting it into the "In progress" state:**

[image: A certificate request that's in progress]

**Download the associated CSR:**

[image: Highlighted Download CSR button]

**Upload (merge) the signed request:**

[image: Highlighted Merge Signed Request button]

**Edit:**

The powershell equivalent returns the CSR with the initial Add-AzKeyVaultCertificate request. So I guess I'm looking/hoping for the same being possible with the dotnet client.

```
$policy = New-AzKeyVaultCertificatePolicy -SubjectName "CN=www.contosoHRApp.com" -ValidityInMonths 1  -IssuerName Unknown
$csr = Add-AzKeyVaultCertificate -VaultName ContosoKV -Name ContosoManualCSRCertificate -CertificatePolicy $policy
$csr.CertificateSigningRequest
```

with the output being

```
Id                        : https://XXX.vault.azure.net/certificates/POWERSHELL/pending
Status                    : inProgress
StatusDetails             : Pending certificate created. Please Perform Merge to complete the request.
RequestId                 : c22693443ae94c70b2603cb8e09ebb2a
Target                    :
Issuer                    : Unknown
CancellationRequested     : False
CertificateSigningRequest : MIICqTCCAZECAQAwGTEXMBUGA1UEAxMOUE9XRVJTSEVMTFRFU1QwggEiMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4IBDwAwggEKAoI
                            BAQDC/Z/CIpVIqeBLLxoMxJxOZIqDhK84ZRDiGtRSqd5SxFOkKWlFaPxuxoLvWzOWphH2HS9gzm0Fg1dHpF7vHzGnY9
                            HTVM41ODhjwM/BVRF+eCjVecrEUXN+dty+ti/R/Nq8q7kgvxQUtY6dZM2R1qkDgJBtYOlhfm9HTdMUxoxXe/sDDpGB4
                            HDIN/5TeoB3IGY4gV/u+zRbQt8Llf9VCLajoubYDiij+LvuFxAftnzX8QB1lXqO7xuyF4I7Be6PCYScQ6OgVhSBhAMC
                            Pd3hdG0MS7nTXAgdFymFio+gZ2Y0HEQxgvIGSCWmXyjEf0OaiQSE6MBeX/1Rw2fHnA3/44bxAgMBAAGgSzBJBgkqhki
                            G9w0BCQ4xPDA6MA4GA1UdDwEB/wQEAwIFoDAdBgNVHSUEFjAUBggrBgEFBQcDAQYIKwYBBQUHAwIwCQYDVR0TBAIwAD
                            ANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQsFAAOCAQEAsL8sWnKBl0x2qy/DDwlJGwOwaQF+SIjtfMxXqLCtFt+Gaa0rOYhbvRSV0G6XZjBc1
                            Foc5eRysxy7Ts90p2Z+sxRNqeOJo83v+bhYKs4KmUKyZmKLW/CG70hpKG/HJBabSD68EaYt1bxKa4s5yjI5bDAQyDIR
                            nYAkGc5zhgVbk68moApMDDDQTVxdgpIoG0rYywHyXSi15GOnXbdWRXObwWu/ReNzn75hmEffChw0a8SYTVurXQDarIY
                            qoCD9nGzE468G9yL8ogvxu5zNZ7C1Sq3j2D7eIDK+KARk8HGY61yMInuLqsANpTy0e8UKuzY3TGxaj7L5CibDsyW6CF
                            Z4Mw==
ErrorCode                 :
ErrorMessage              :
Name                      :
VaultName                 :
```

Comment: I'm able to achieve the same in REST API. Is it okay if I provide answer by calling that REST API using HTTP client in dotnet?

Comment: @Sridevi please be my guest thank you!

Comment: @Sridevi sorry I think I may have found what I'm after using the dotnet client, I don't want to waste your time so don't worry! I'll post what I've got as an answer when I've checked it

Answer (score 0):

I believe what I was looking for is the following. It seems like setting the issuer to "Unknown" is important in getting the certificate into the "In Progress" state.

The actual CSR is returned from the `StartCreateCertificate` method via the `Properties.Csr` `byte[]`

```cs
private string CreatePendingCertAndGetCSR()
{

    var certificateName = "CERT_NAME";

    var policy = new CertificatePolicy("Unknown", $"CN={certificateName}")
    {
        ValidityInMonths = 12,
        KeySize = 4096,
        KeyType = CertificateKeyType.Rsa,
        ContentType = CertificateContentType.Pkcs12
    };

    policy.LifetimeActions.Add(new LifetimeAction(CertificatePolicyAction.EmailContacts)
    {
        DaysBeforeExpiry = 30
    });

    var operation = await _client.StartCreateCertificateAsync(certificateName, policy);

    var csr = operation.Properties.Csr;
    var str = Convert.ToBase64String(csr);

    return $"{CSR_PREFIX}\n{str}\n{CSR_SUFFIX}";
}

private const string CSR_PREFIX = "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----";
private const string CSR_SUFFIX = "-----END CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----";
```

When the certificate is issued I can then call `_client.MergeCertificateAsync` to get that updated.